# What php code can I put in a JOOMLA custom HTML module to display a page_heading - using Sourcerer

Tags: php, joomla

In JOOMLA, I need to display the "page heading" in a module so I can move the heading to different locations.

I am using sourcerer to do this in a custom html module.

I also need to display the article title. Thanks another question on here I have the code for this.

can someone help me with the code to display the "Page Heading" field from the page display tab of a menu item?

Thanks

Comment: Hi zambego! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get better answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you'll get the article title, as many "pages" in Joomla are not individual articles.

You should be able to get the page heading though, using the following code in your module.

```
{source}
<?php
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    echo $doc->title;
?>
{/source}
```

From the general Sourcerer docs  https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#php is useful, and the details on available joomla objects and variables in Sourcerer https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#what-variables-objects-does-sourcerer-have-ready-for-use